# Does a bounded well-ordered set have a maximum?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

Suppose $(A,\preccurlyeq)$ is a well-ordered [chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order), i.e., every subset $B\subseteq A$ has a least element under the order $\preccurlyeq$.

We say that a set $B\subseteq A$ is bounded if there exists $s\in A$ such that $b\preccurlyeq s$ for all $b\in B$.

> **Question:** Does every bounded subset of $A$ have a maximum?

If $B$ is finite this is obviously true, since we can start with the minimum $m=\min B$, and keep applying the successor operation
$$x^+=\min\textstyle_{\preccurlyeq}(B\smallsetminus\{b\in B: b\preccurlyeq x\})$$
and stop when we end up with a singleton $\{M\}$, this will be the maximum of $B$. But what if $B$ is infinite?

I can't think of an easy counterexample to this, it feels like it should be true.

Comment: Have you considered $A = \{-\frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}_+\} \cup \{0\}$ and $B = A \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: @DanRust No I have not   Do you want to type it up as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we let $A = \{-\frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}_+\} \cup \{0\}$ with the usual order, then $A$ is well-ordered. Now take $B = A \setminus\{0\}$ which is bounded, as $0$ is an upper bound for $B$, but as $0$ is not an element of $B$, and no other element of $A$ provides an upper bound for $B$, it follows that $B$ has no maximum.

Comment: Thanks for this! I actually edited my question a bit, could you take a look?

Comment: I feel like you should really be making this a new question, as your edit completely changes the content of your original question.

Comment: you are right, I will do that.